# Why does the clusthr function on my SpatialPointsDataFrame return back a script out of bounds error?

Tags: r, r-sp, adehabitathr

I am trying to calculate MCP and KDE on a vhf tracking data, my dataframe has three columns, Individual, Lat and Long.

I am trying following the adahabitatHR vignette to try and create a SpatialPointsDataFrame that contains vhf data on multiple individuals (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/adehabitatHR/vignettes/adehabitatHR.pdf), but using my own dataset.

## I load my data

```
vhf <- read.csv("vhfdatacrom.csv")`
str(vhf)
```

> data.frame':  186 obs. of  3 variables:
>    $ Individual: Factor w/ 12 levels "PM01","PM03",..: 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 4 ...
>   $ Lat       : num  54.2 54.2 54.2 54.2 54.2 ...
>   $ Long      : num  -7.44 -7.42 -7.45 -7.44 -7.42 ...

```
> coords.data.xy <- vhf[c("Long", "Lat")]
> id <- vhf[c("Individual")]
> idsp <- data.frame(id)
> coordinates(idsp) <- coords.data.xy
> class(idsp)
```

[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"

```
> clusthr(idsp)
```

Error in tmp[1, ] : subscript out of bounds

I have tinkered all I can but cannot get this to run, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you